# GNOME 3 FN + Arrow causes crossed out circle to display

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, ubuntu-gnome

I am on an ASUS ROG G752VL running Ubuntu 16.04 GNOME 3. Whenever I press FN + left,right,up, or down arrow, a crossed out circle appears. Is this fixable? I am trying to use FN + left/right arrow similarly to CMD + Arrow on MacOS which I believe is the intended default implementation on Ubuntu 16.04 with GNOME 3.

[Crossed out arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaJAs.png)

Using `sudo xev` and pressing FN + Left Arrow I get

```
FocusIn event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 39, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  4294967241 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0   0   
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

and pressing FN + Right Arrow I also get

```
FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  4294967241 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Strangely, however, on my second press in a row I always get

```
FocusIn event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

with FN + right and

```
FocusIn event, serial 44, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 44, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

with FN + left.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know how MacOs Works, but you can customize the keyboard short cuts on Gnome, Please follow the steps on this link 
https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en

Comment: MacOS CMD+Arrow goes to the end/beginning of a line based on the direction of the key. I am almost sure this is how FN+Arrow is supposed to behave on GNOME.

Comment: oh!, i think i understand you now. And yes and not, it's depends on your keyboard and your keyboard driver. I gues a mac keyboard driver may not be at all compatible. You can either search and install another driver one of a pc keyboard that seems more to yours. Or just by hand change the shortcuts.